# mongodb aggregation pipeline - convert array entries to subdocument

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on a mongodb aggregation pipeline.  I currently have the following document:

```
{
  "data": [
    { "type": "abc", "price": 25000, "inventory": 15 },
    { "type": "def", "price": 8000, "inventory": 150 }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to turn it in:

```
{
    "abc": { "price": 25000, "inventory": 15 },
    "def": { "price": 8000, "inventory": 150 }
}
```

I could do it field by field with a `$project` stage, but obviously my real example has way more fields then this simple example...  And I also have no certainty about which values could be in type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **@Joe** I managed to create a solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: [
        "$data.type",
        {
          price: "$data.price",
          inventory: "$data.inventory"
        }
      ],          
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      doc: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$doc.data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "abc": {
      "inventory": 15,
      "price": 25000
    },
    "def": {
      "inventory": 150,
      "price": 8000
    }
  }
]
```

Mongo [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vXhDgQSEFAo)

Answer (score 2):

Since `data` is an array, you could use an aggregation pipeline similar to:

- $unwind to split those into separate documents each containing a single item
- $project to change it from `{type:x, price:y, inventory:z}` to `[x,[{price:y, inventory:z}]]`
- $group to collect the items back to a single array of arrays
- $arrayToObject to convert the array of arrays to `[{x:{price:y,inventory:z}},...]`

If you need more detail, I can see about working up a sample when I have a bit more time.